# I am looking for and example of how to use Plc4xSinkProcessor in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, modbus, apache-plc4x, plc4x

I currently have Plc4xSourceProcessor working in NiFi thanks to the  [Apache NiFi](https://plc4x.apache.org/users/integrations/apache-nifi.html) walk through. I have Modbus data coming from a Modbus slave to the Plc4xSourceProcessor. That processor is connected to a PutTcp processor that sends it to another NiFi server with a ListenTcp Processor which is attached to the Plc4xSinkProcessor.  At this point I am not sure what to do or how to configure the Plc4xSinkProcesor.  Is it supposed to be connected to another ModbusSlave,or a ModbusPoll application?

Answer (score 0):

The Plc4xSinkProcessor should be able to connect and write data to a Modbus Slave.